# Make Page Viewer WebPart automatically refresh

Tags: web-part, 2013, refresh

Is it possible to make a page viewer webpart automatically refresh or upgrade?

I have a report image which I am replacing every 15 minutes with a script but the Page Viewer on SharePoint isn't updating to reflect.

Comment: Can't you just refresh the page where the viewer is placed with some JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply apply your settings and add this snippet to your page:

```
(function () {
      //this snippet reloads an iframe on the page in a set interval
      function getIFrameBySrc(src){
        var matchingElements = [];
        //shim for querySelector heavily stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/can-i-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-when-queryselectorall-is-not-available
        if(typeof document.querySelector == "undefined") {
            var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
            for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++)
            {
              console.log(allElements[i]);
              if (allElements[i].getAttribute('src') === src)
              {
                // Element exists with attribute. Add to array.
                matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
              }
            }
        } else{
          matchingElements = document.querySelectorAll('iframe[src-' + src + ']');
        }
        return matchingElements;
      }

      var iframes = getIFrameBySrc('http://www.w3schools.com'); //add the target url here

      function reloadIframe(){
        for(var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++){
          //better but only works on same origin pages
          /*iframes[i].contentWindow.location.reload(true);*/

          //does not work in certain versions of chrome
          iframes[i].src = iframes[i].src;

          //more info here 
          // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064850/how-to-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript
        }
      }
      //if used on mds pages you need to check before setting this up multiple times
      setInterval(reloadIframe, 5000);//time in ms it takes to refresh 
}());
```

Remember to check if you already attached a interval for MDS pages.

**[Live example](http://liveweave.com/DtWFns)**

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the Page Viewer Web Part you could use the HTML Form Web Part and put the required javascript and iframe in to make this happen.